# Magento 2: How do I override a core template using a custom module for a single store?

Tags: templates, module, overriding, magento2

I want to customize the `/checkout/success` template file (`success.phtml`). I have a custom module built that overrides the core `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Checkout/Onepage/Success` block and adds data into `prepareData()`. If I add the template file within my module (`Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\success.phtml`), everything is great: no problem loading and rendering the additional data in the phtml.

The problem is that I only want to set the override for a single store - so normally I would put the new template in `app/design/frontend/[theme]/[themename]/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml` - and expect that that would trump the core version, but that doesn't seem to be working if I have a module overriding that template already.

How do you configure a theme/store level template using a custom module Block, and let other stores use the core template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out: within the theme's directory structure, you need to specify the *extended* module name, not the core module name. You still need to have a template file within the module with the block extension (which seems clunky - why not just use core by default?) so I copied the core template to the module, then was able to specify the theme level template as `app/design/frontend/[themeparent]/[themename]/Vendor_Module/template/success.phtml` rather than `app/design/frontend/[themeparent]/[themename]/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml`.

All themes use the extended modules template (copy of core) and the specific theme uses it's own template.